# Self and super in nix overlays

Tags: nix

In nix, overlay is a function with 2 arguments: `self` and `super`. Based on the [manual](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#chap-overlays), `self` corresponds to the final package set (or some others call it result of the fix point calculation) and only to be used when dealing with dependencies. While `super` is the result of the evaluation of the previous stages of `nixpkgs` and only to be used when you refer to packages you want to override or to access certain function.

Sadly I don't really understand this. In what way that the `nixpkgs` gets updated by the overlays such that there's 2 restriction mentioned above?

Comment: @DavidGrayson Sorry if I'm not clear enough. The 2 restrictions I mentioned above are: `self` is only to be used when dealing with dependencies, `super` is only to be used when we need to refer to packages or to use certain function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These restrictions follow from the requirement that evaluation of an attribute should terminate.

Suppose you want to override the `hello` package. To reference the old definition of the package, you need to use `super.hello`, because that attribute can be evaluated without evaluating the `hello` definition in your overlay. If you would instead reference `self.hello`, that means that for evaluating the final `hello` attribute, Nix will have to evaluate `self.hello`, which references the final `hello` attribute, which references `self.hello`, and so on, creating an infinite recursion.

`self` can actually be used to reference functions, but the convention seems to be to use `super` instead. The idea that the next overlay may monkey-patch the `lib.head` function is not very enticing, although using `super` the same can still be done in a previous overlay.

You may also want to check out [this excellent NixCon 2017 presentation by Nicolas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W85mF1zWA2o). He both introduces the concept and explains how you can use it in the best way.

Comment: edit queue is full ... nevermind ... will delete comment later